# How can I deal with RMagick leaking on non-Image objects?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

So I know that RMagick leaks all over the place with `Image` objects, and that `#destroy!` frees up that memory.

However, I'm writing a script that iterates through all the pixels of an image, and I have to deal with the fact that even RMagick's other objects, including `Pixel`, leak all over.

```
image = Magick::Image::read('/path/to/image.png')[0]
5.times do
  100000.times do
    image.pixel_color(0,0)
  end
  print "Check memory, then press enter";gets
end
```

Run and watch it leak all over the place. Just by reading pixels.

**How can I iterate over these pixels without leaking like crazy?** I'm interested in RMagick solutions, non-RMagick solutions, and even non-Ruby solutions if need be (but I'd really rather not).

---

In case there's already a tool for this specific task that I can't find a search query for, here's what I'm doing: I have two images that were generated by overlaying an RGBA image on a solid-color background (in this case, one black and one white). This script does some simple math to retrieve the original image, alpha transparency and all. I couldn't find a command-line tool to do this exact job, but, then again, it's not exactly easy to put into a short phrase.

Comment: Might be an idea to use CImg Library, write a little C++ lib and use it using FFI from ruby `http://cimg.sourceforge.net/` and `https://github.com/ffi/ffi`

Comment: also depending on the math etc you are doing you might be able to use `https://github.com/banister/devil` and the filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I've opted to use [ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png), a pure Ruby library, to avoid RMagick's leakiness. I may add the C extension [OilyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/oily_png) to that setup in the near future.

I'm accepting this answer for the time being, since it solves my particular problem. However, if anyone finds a solution that actually addresses the core issue of RMagick's memory leaks on non-images, please post it anyway :D Thanks!